# how to hide tool bar,statusbar and tablayout in first fragment tab,like snap chat full screen fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had 3 fragments when after Edit my code it working but not exact i want,i want like Snap Chat,swipe mode ,when i change my fragment again i am getting first tab name their but i don't what show again my tab one tab name please any one help me how to get this

here below my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
int FIRST_PAGE=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == FIRST_PAGE) {
                getSupportActionBar().hide();
                tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                getSupportActionBar().show();
                tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   adapter.addFragment(new Paea(),"one");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecMain(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new SecMain(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }



}
```

when i add below code getting output not exact i want,when i swipe to second tab again their my first tab name was getting please any one help how to hide that 
here below my image 
[image]

[image]

how to hide one tab name in my tablayout

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `OnPageChangeListener` to your `ViewPager`. Then in its `onPageSelected` method, you could check if the selected page is first page or not.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             if(position == FIRST_PAGE) {
                  getSupportActionBar().hide();
                  tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
             else {
                  getSupportActionBar().show();
                  tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i am getting this error can't resolve addOnPageChangeListener@Eric B

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest support libraries in your `build.gradle`. I am using these `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`, `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` and i don't get such an error.

Comment: yes am also using same libraries but still i am getting getting error@Eric B

Comment: Try doing a clean build.

Comment: yes it working but that was not my requirement,i need my first tab like snapchat fragment full screen fragment but still it showing tab name @Eric B

Comment: it working fine but not getting exact output,when i select first tab tablayout gone but when i select second tab in their my first tab visible their i dont what to visible in their@Eric B

Comment: Well to do this, you can simply remove the `TabLayout` from your XML. Instead of the `TabLayout` add a `LinearLayout` and make 2 tab like views in them. Then using the `onPageSelected` listener, you can show a tab as selected or not.